# how to emulate nfc card in a flutter?

Tags: flutter, nfc

i would like to expose informations through my flutter application so that we can read them with nfc technology. in other terms i would like to emulate nfc card with application. what i tried to do is implement the example of this flutter package [nfc_emulator](https://pub.dev/packages/nfc_emulator)
this is the sample code i got from the example in package documentation:

```
 NfcEmulator.startNfcEmulator("666B65630001", "cd22c716" "79e64d05ed6475d3acf405d6a9cd506b");
```

but what i readed from this does not corresponding to any of this parameters i exposed. i got set of letters and numbers like **80 df...**